# Footer is not responsive

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I am trying to make my app responsive, but I have a problem because Footer is not responsive.
I read this [link](http://galengidman.com/2014/03/25/responsive-flexible-height-sticky-footers-in-css/) but this didn't worked for me.

```
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="top">
            @include('includes.top')
        </div>
        <div id="left">
            @include('includes.left')
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
        <div id="right">

        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            @include('includes.footer')
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

styles.css

```
html,
body { height: 100%; }
body {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
#footer {
  display: table-row;
  height: 1px;
}
#content { height: 100%; }
```

Comment: Can you define "responsive"? What do you want it to do? What is it actually doing?

Comment: jsfiddle or it didn't happen :-)

Comment: Plus to @FDL question, your content div takes 100% height, watch out ;)

Comment: http://galengidman.com/2014/03/25/responsive-flexible-height-sticky-footers-in-css/ like he explains the prblem. I want to push footer to the bottom of the page

Comment: make wrap your "table" with height 100% and then all the direct child divs within  `display: table-row;` - http://jsfiddle.net/M9wDv/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the link you posted (*in the comments*) does not implement it the way you do ..

Your html should be (*according to that article*)

```
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="top">
            @include('includes.top')
        </div>
        <div id="left">
            @include('includes.left')
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
        <div id="right">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        @include('includes.footer')
    </div>
</body>
```

and your css

```
html,
body { height: 100%; }
body {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
#footer {
  display: table-row;
  height: 1px;
}
#wrap{ display: table-row; height: 100%; }
```

And a demo of this code at http://jsfiddle.net/LFeYA/